# Unable to connect to mongodb databse using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to connect to mongodb from node.js using `mongoose` as database driver. Also I am getting the following error.

**Error:**

```
Error in DB connection:{"ok":0,"code":18,"codeName":"AuthenticationFailed","name":"MongoError"}
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbUser = process.env.USERNAME || 'admin';
const dbPass = process.env.PASSWORD || 'admin';
const dbServer = 'edqart-mongodb';
const dbPort = process.env.MONGO_PORT || '27017';
let dbName = 'edqart-db';
const url = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPass}@${dbServer}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`;
console.log('url', url);
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 5000000,
    poolSize: 10000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
};

/*
 1- Connect to mongo server
*/

mongoose.connect(url, options, (err) => {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('Mongodb connection with mongoose successed');
    } else {
        console.log('Error in DB connection:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, true));
    }
})
```

Here the database `edqart-db` is not actually present inside that particular mongo server. I need once one record will insert the `db` will created dynamically. If I have `let dbName = 'admin';` then my node is connected to mongodb but for other db which is not created from beginning its showing error. I need once one record is going to insert then the db `edqart-db` will created. Here I just need the similar method like `client.db(dbName)` of `require('mongodb').MongoClient` for `mongoose` also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to authenticate on non existing db.

Here is what you should do if you want to enable auth on `edqart-db`.

- Create a database `edqart-db`.
- Create a user on that `edqart-db`. lets say `username=edqartReadUser` and `password=edqartReasPassword`.
- Then your existing code should work below url.

```
const dbUser = process.env.USERNAME || 'edqartReadUser';
const dbPass = process.env.PASSWORD || 'edqartReasPassword';
const dbServer = 'edqart-mongodb';
const dbPort = process.env.MONGO_PORT || '27017';
let dbName = 'edqart-db';
const url = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPass}@${dbServer}:${dbPort}/${dbName}`;
```